# un rotate element using filter in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation

I have the html structure like this

```
<div class="block>
   content
   <span class="child">text</span>
</div>
```

in css i said:

```
.block{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.99254615, M12=0.12186934, M21=-0.12186934, M22=0.99254615, sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

So that the block will rotate minus 7degree. However, I don't want span.child to be rotate. (and I don't want to take it out side the block class)

What should i do in css in order to not rotate the child element (no javascript please)

Comment: could you un-rotate `.block span`?

Answer (score 1):

I have no Idea about the filter you are using, but wouldn't a common sense approach be applying a second filter to rotate it back seven degrees?

If that is not workable, I don't see a way without taking the element out of the block.

Answer (score 1):

This clears the filter:

```
.child
{
    filter: none;
}
```